# Cannot open connection to JDBC SQLite Database in Android due to Read-only file system

Tags: android, jdbc, android-sqlite

I am creating an app that requires connecting to a SQLite database. To do this I am using JDBC SQLite and I am doing it in this way:

```
final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:mydb.sqlite";

// Open a database connection
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
```

I then created a JUnit test class to test methods on my database and everything works exactly how it should.

When I try calling the exact same methods from within an activity, opening the connection to the database fails and I get this message:

```
opening db: 'mydb.sqlite': Read-only file system
```

A couple of other notes:

- I am using an emulator, not an actual device
- I do not have any problems when I am opening the database connection from a test class, only when I open it from an app Activity